# Display only some digits of an Int

Tags: swift

Let's say you have an Int.

```
let int = 12345
```

I want it to only display some of the digits.
For example: print(firstTwoDigits) --> 12

How do I do this and thank you in advance.

Comment: It's [**digits**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_digit), not [**numbers**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number).

Comment: The accepted answer is O(n). Instead of using a String and back to an integer, we can have an O(1) solution : we can use the relationship between an integer and the number of its digits : `func keepFirst(_ digits: Int, from n: Int) -> Int {
    guard case let numberOfDigits = Int(log10(Double(n))) + 1, digits <= numberOfDigits, digits >= 0 else { fatalError("Invalid number of digits to keep") }; let power = Int(pow(10.0, Double(numberOfDigits - digits))); return n / power }`

Comment: @Carpsen90 you would need to make sure also that `n > 0` otherwise this would crash your app. Try  `keepFirst(1, from: 0)`

Comment: @LeoDabus Good catch 

Comment: @Carpsen90 I would dosomething like `extension BinaryInteger {
    var digits: [Int] {
        var digits: [Int] = []
        var value = abs(Int(self))
        while value > 0 {
            digits.insert(value % 10, at: 0)
            value /= 10
        }
        return digits
    }
}` and return the collection `prefix(n)`

Comment: @Carpsen90, ah, **do not** use `fatalError` where `throw` should be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your specific requirements.

This prints the first two digits of an integer number

```
let intVal = 12345
print(String(intVal).prefix(2))
```

> Output: 12

Another way which only prints certain ones in the number:

```
let intVal = 12345
let acceptableValues = ["1", "2"]

let result = String(intVal).filter {
    acceptableValues.contains(String($0))
}
print(result)
```

> Output: 12